# Displaying an array that's within an array

Tags: php, arrays, json

Say I have this array, how would I assign variables to the values behind A,B,C,D and E?
This is my code:

```
<?php
$request = "https://www.kimonolabs.com/api/6xlbn85i?apikey=daicEIFxONdoVm18BArKo8UekZJE1P6c&bondsnummer=21169152";

$response = file_get_contents($request);
$results = json_decode($response, TRUE);
print_r($results);
echo '<pre>'; print_r($results); echo '</pre>';
?>
```

And this is my output:

```
Array
(
    [name] => Tennismix2
    [count] => 1
    [frequency] => On demand
    [version] => 11
    [newdata] => 
    [lastrunstatus] => success
    [lastsuccess] => Wed Nov 19 2014 08:34:23 GMT+0000 (UTC)
    [thisversionrun] => Wed Nov 19 2014 08:34:21 GMT+0000 (UTC)
    [thisversionstatus] => success
    [url] => http://status.mandrillapp.com/
    [results] => Array
        (
            [collection1] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [A] => 21169152
                            [B] => Baal, A.J.W. van
                            [C] => M
                            [D] => 3
                            [E] => 3
                        )

                )

        )

)
```

We used a API (kimonolabs) to scrape data from a website but this is the furthest we can get.
All help appreciated.

Comment: To assing value to this array just use : `$results['results']['collection1']['0']['A'] = "your new value";`

Answer (score 1):

```
$var1 =  $results['results']['collection1']['0']['A'];
$var2 =  $results['results']['collection1']['0']['B'];
$var3 =  $results['results']['collection1']['0']['C'];
$var4 =  $results['results']['collection1']['0']['D'];
$var5 =  $results['results']['collection1']['0']['E'];
```